# Is there any way to send the stdout of a Process to SLF4J?

Tags: java, slf4j

I'm essentially doing the following:

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder().command( ... ).start();
InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();
LoggerFactory.getLogger( this.class ).debug...?
```

Is there any way to write the `InputStream` to the logger so that it's managed by my logging settings? Or is there another approach I should take to capture the process output?

**update**: I've rewritten this because I just realized I had read the `Process/ProcessBuilder` API wrong and that `getInputStream()` is STDOUT

**update 2** Ideally the way that this would be achieved would allow me to process both stdout/stderr as they come (line at a time) and not some time later.

Answer (score 4):

If you're willing to use a library, [zt-exec](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-exec) is very convenient and can redirect the stdout and stderr of the process to SLF4J.

For example, to redirect stdout to info level and stderr to error level of the logger of the calling class:

```
new ProcessExecutor().command("java", "-version")
        .redirectOutput(Slf4jStream.ofCaller().asInfo())
        .redirectError(Slf4jStream.ofCaller().asError())
        .execute();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an edited snippet of the class that I use

```
public class CommandLineLogger {
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CommandLineLogger.class);

  public void logStandardOutput(InputStream inputStream) {
    display("stdout", inputStream);    
  }

  private void display(String identifier, InputStream inputStream) {
    logger.debug("Printing output from {}", identifier);
    try {
      String formattedIdentifier = identifier + ":";
      logInputStream(formattedIdentifier, inputStream);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  private void logInputStream(String outputType, InputStream inputStream) throws Exception {
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
    BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    while (true) {
      String line = bufferReader.readLine();
      if (line != null) {
        logger.debug(outputType + ": " + line);
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```