# Logging large string causes OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, spring, performance, logging, logback

My Spring Boot web application connects to many external services and it has a requirement to write all requests and responses to and from the services to log files.

I use Logback for the log engine. And following code is for printing the response message to log files.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

....

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RequestLoggingClientRequestInterceptor.class);

...

ClientHttpResponse response = execution.execute(request, body);
InputStream s = response.getBody();
String loggingResponseBody = new String(ByteStreams.toByteArray(s), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
LOG.info("response status code: {}, response headers: {}, response body: {}",
            response.getStatusCode(),
            response.getHeaders(),
            loggingResponseBody);
```

This code has performance problem. It consumes high CPU, causes high latency and, in some case where the response message is very large, it causes an `OutOfMemoryError` in execution of `new String(ByteStreams.toByteArray(s), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));`

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.lang.StringCoding.decode(StringCoding.java:215)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:463)
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:515)
    at ...
```

Note that I have no specific requirement to decode the string to 'UTF-8', I just did so because the constructor of the `String` class suggests.

Please suggest how to improve the code to solve the performance problem. I have tried `AsyncAppender`, though it helps with the latency, I am stuck with the `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: You can do something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416711/is-there-any-way-to-send-the-stdout-of-a-process-to-slf4j)

Comment: Is this a service which collects and prints logs from all services ? How big is the response body that causes OOM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A ClientHttpResponse must be closed (as specified), which `ByteStreams.toByteArray(s)` does not (as specified).

```
try (InputStream s = response.getBody()) {
    LOG.info("response status code: {}, response headers: {}, response body:",
            response.getStatusCode(),
            response.getHeaders());
    String loggingResponseBody = new String(ByteStreams.toByteArray(s),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    LOG.info(loggingResponseBody); // One param means no format with {}
}
```

So it might just be a resource leak. The code seems brittle, as it must be certain that the response is UTF-8 text and not exceeding senseless megabytes.

Comment: You are right, it's a resource leak problem. Thank you.